# How to change tooltip background color in Eclipse PDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

How do I change Eclipse PDT background color of tooltip, which is shown by pressing CTRL and hovering variable? Here's the tooltip I meant:

[image: CTRL + hover tooltip]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: This should be in _Window > Preferences: Colors and Fonts_ the _Basic > Information background color_? Otherwise, tell which Eclipse version do you use.

Comment: @howlger unfortunately not - it is set to white. I'm using Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0).